# How to set the initial script in a TinyMCE textarea?

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce

Can i set the initial script in tinymce? the script that save on database is :

```
<pre class="language-php"><code>&lt;script src=""&gt;&lt;/script&gt; </code></pre>
```

I use this code

```
//I use laravel
<textarea name="text" id="tinyarea">{!! $post->text !!}</textarea>
```

When i want load this code only below code put on the tinymce textarea

```
<pre class="language-php">&nbsp;</pre>
```

English isn’t my first language, so please excuse any mistakes.